# Как правильно изменить CSS, HTML код в Wiki js (установлен локально на мой компьютер через Docker Desktop)

Tags: javascript, docker-compose

Вопрос по wiki.js

Как правильно изменить CSS, HTML код в Wiki.js (Сама wiki установлена локально на мой компьютер через Docker Desktop)

В самой Wiki.js есть возможность встраивания CSS кода, встраиваю, но изменений не видно... (скриншот прикладываю)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть есть ещё какие то способы как изменить CSS и HTML? Я всего лишь хочу изменить внешний вид wiki, покрасить её, не портя стандартные стили.

Comment: А если вот так написть путь (.v-application .black .v-toolbar__content) тоже нет изменений?